# How to interact with exchange web services using oAuth for Daemon but only for one mailbox

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices

I understand that basic authentication for EWS is going away. I have a need for a service (daemon) to monitor a mailbox for incoming mail.

I've setup an application in Azure and I have the daemon running which can get the token successfully.

The issue I am having is that it seems the application will have access to every mailbox. I do not want my application to have access to the mailbox of each user that exists in exchange, but just to one mailbox. Either this does not exist, or I cannot seem to find where to set this up so it is granular to one mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, AFAIK, you get access to the entire Exchange, which seems very bad.  I am going to try to get thru the support chain to see if my registered app can be given a scope of mailboxes rather than the whole deal.  If I get an answer I'll post back here.  Perhaps someone else will chime in while I'm off on my quest.

Comment: This IS bad. They are telling people not to use basic auth and the alternative makes no sense at all.